# Translating Linq expression in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to convert this code:

```
var query2 = from b in db.MU_Reports
             join downtime in db.Downtime_Reports on b.Shift equals downtime.Shift
             where downtime.Downtime_Code.Equals("9185")
             group downtime by new { b.Date, b.Shift, b.Machine_Number, b.MU } into g
             select new
             {
                 Date = g.Key.Date,
                 Shift = g.Key.Shift,
                 Machine = g.Key.Machine_Number,
                 MU = g.Key.MU,
                 No_Work_Hours = g.Sum(x => x.Total_DownTime)
             };
```

To look something like this one:

```
var query = db.MU_Reports.Join(db.Downtime_Reports, b=> b.Shift, c=> c.Shift, (b , c) => new { b, thisshift = c })
            .Where(n => n.thisshift.Down_TIme_Codes.Equals("9185"))
            .GroupBy(d=> new { d.b.Date, d.b.Shift, d.b.Machine_Number, d.b.MU }, d => d.b)
            .Select (g=> new
            {
                Date = g.Key.Date,
                Shift = g.Key.Shift,
                Machine = g.Key.Machine_Number,
                MU = g.Key.MU,
                No_Work_Hours = g.Sum(i => i.Total_DownTime)
            }).ToList();
```

As you can see I am very close. My only issue is the last statement `No_Work_Hours = g.Sum(i => i.Total_DownTime)` It is trying to get the `Total_DownTime` from `db.MU_Reports` but it needs to come from `db.Downtime_Reports`. I am new to c# and am doing this to understand the program I created better.

Comment: Shouldn't your second argument to `GroupBy` be `d => d.thisshift` instead of `d => d.b`?

Comment: @juharr no because `MU` only exists in `d.b.MU` not in `d.thisshift.MU`

Comment: Read carefully the @juharr comment and try again.

Comment: @JCM You get `MU` from the `Key` created by the first argument to `GroupBy` not from the items you group in the second.

Answer (score 2):

Your second argument to `GroupBy` should be `d => d.thisshift` instead of `d => d.b`.  That corresponds to the `group downtime by`, but by doing `d => d.b` it's like you're doing `group b by`

```
var query = db.MU_Reports
    .Join(
        db.Downtime_Reports, 
        b=> b.Shift, 
        c=> c.Shift, 
        (b , c) => new { b, thisshift = c })
    .Where(n => n.thisshift.Down_TIme_Codes.Equals("9185"))
    .GroupBy(
        d=> new { d.b.Date, d.b.Shift, d.b.Machine_Number, d.b.MU }, 
        d => d.thisshift)
    .Select (g=> new
    {
        Date = g.Key.Date,
        Shift = g.Key.Shift,
        Machine = g.Key.Machine_Number,
        MU = g.Key.MU,
        No_Work_Hours = g.Sum(i => i.Total_DownTime)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: From my understanding you are telling me to do this `.GroupBy(d=> new { d.thisshift.Date, d.thisshift.Shift, d.thisshift.Machine_Number}, d => d.b)` however I still have the same issue but now I do not get `MU`

Comment: `MU` is part of the anonymous class you create for your `Key` that you create with the first lambda.  Changing the second should have no effect on that part.

Comment: @JCM No, only change the second argument.

Comment: @JCM I just added the corrected code.  You were changing the first argument to `GroupBy`.  I'm saying you need to change only the second.